# weird C++ constructor/copy constructor issues in g++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
        public:
                X() {
                        cout<<"Cons"<<endl;
                }
                X(const X& x){
                        cout<<"Copy"<<endl;
                }
                void operator=(const X& x){
                        cout<<"Assignment called";
                }
};

X& fun() {
        X s;
        return s;
}

int main(){
        X s = fun();
        return 0;
}
```

This code calls the copy constructor also. Why does this work? I recall that the first time I ran this program, it seg faulted. But after a while, it started calling this copy cons. and now works!! Wierd.

But if I replace, fun() as follows:

```
X fun() {
        X s;
        return s;
}
```

Then copy cons. is not called. I thought that the copy cons. would be called in this case. But as pointed out by @flyfishr64, RVO is coming into play here. But it still does not explain the case where I am returning a reference. I think it should always segfault.

Any explanations?

Comment: You can't just say "But after a while, it started calling this copy cons. and now works!!" - you must have changed something.

Comment: Nope. The only thing I did was add 1 cout and then remove it.

Comment: Quite possible. Because when I tried the following, the copy constructor was not called. 

X& fun() { X s; return s; } int main(){ X& x = fun(); return 0; } 


But with this theory, does it not mean, that returning a reference of a local variable is always valid? Because if I do X s = fun() in the main, the copy constructor is anyway getting called ?

Comment: No, a reference to a local is invalid, but only if you try to dereference it. Merely returning it is perfectly fine. Futhermore, dereferencing it is "undefined behavior", and that doesn't necessarily mean "segfault", it means just that - undefined. Anything at all may happen, and one particular isntance of "anything" is the object pretending it's still alive, which will most likely what you see if you actually try to use the returned value (since you haven't overwritten the stack frame on which the local was allocated yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @flyfishr64's answer

The copy constructor is invoked here because this:

```
X s = fun();
```

is an initialization. You are using fun() to construct the object, not invoking the default constructor. It is equivalent to:

```
X s(fun());
```

The "Cons" you see printed out is for the instance in fun(). See this article: [Assignment operator in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_in_C%2B%2B) for more.

Answer (score 4):

This returns reference to an object on stack which does not exist once the method returns - the stack is unwinded, the memory is still there but you should not be using it

```
X& fun() {
        X s;
        return s;
}
```

When you change that to:

```
X fun() {
        X s;
        return s;
}
```

You are now returning a copy. If the compiler is clever enough it might do:

```
X fun() {
    return X();
}
```

In that case the `X` is allocated directly in the callers stack so that copy is not required.

If it segfault or not depends on if you are accessing invalid memory.

In your example you don't access any values from the structure. To see segfault, first keep a reference that you returned with `fun()` add some variables into structure `X` and after return from `fun()` call another method that internally allocates some memory on stack (this should overwrite the original memory used by `X` in `fun`) and stores some values on stack (preferable 0's). After this second method returns try to print out values from the `X` using the original reference returned from `fun` ...

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
X fun() {
        X s;
        return s;
}
```

the copy constructor isn't getting called because of the Return Value Optimization which allows the compiler to bypass creating the local variable 's' and construct X directly in the returned variable.

You can read more about RVO [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Answer (score 0):

When you return a reference to a local variable like that, you're invoking undefinied behaviour.

It happens to work in this case because none of the functions of `class X` actually use the `this` pointer, so it doesn't matter that it's no longer valid.

Comment: Merely returning such a reference invokes UB? You have reference for that?